# Recovering from IndexedDB blocked events without versionchange

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I'm trying to write some tests against an `IndexedDB` library.

In doing so, I am deliberately creating a `blocked` event through a call to `open()` with a higher version against an already-opened database.

While I can circumvent the blocking by closing the database in a `versionchange` listener set up on the earlier version during the first `open()`, for testing purposes, I would like to avoid adding this `versionchange` listener and instead let the `blocked` event be fully triggered so I can confirm my `onblocked` listeners are working properly.

The problem is that making a call to close the database at this stage does not seem to help undo the blocking, with subsequent calls to delete the same database also receiving `blocked` events (in both Firefox and Chrome). I therefore cannot continue with further testing after this blocking code's execution.

Is there no way to recover from a `blocked` event without using a previously-added `versionchange` listener?

Here's the code:

```
var DB_NAME = 'test', DB_VERSION = 1, NEW_DB_VERSION = 2;
indexedDB.deleteDatabase(DB_NAME);

var data = [{
    firstName: 'Brett',
    lastName: 'Zamir',
    age: 43
}, {
    firstName: 'Jane',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    age: 40
}, {
    firstName: 'Bob',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    age: 42
}];

var req = indexedDB.open(DB_NAME, DB_VERSION);
req.onerror = function (evt) {
    console.error("openDb:", evt.target.errorCode);
};
req.onsuccess = function (evt) {
    var db = this.result;

};
req.onupgradeneeded = function (e) {
    var db = e.target.result;
    var os = db.createObjectStore('test', {
        keyPath: 'id',
        autoIncrement: true
    });
    os.transaction.oncomplete = function () {
        var testTx = db.transaction('test', 'readwrite');
        testTx.oncomplete = function () {
            console.log('storage completed');
            fireBlockedEvent(db);
        };
        var testStore = testTx.objectStore('test');
        for (var i in data) {
            testStore.add(data[i]);
        }
    };
};

function fireBlockedEvent (db) {
    var req = indexedDB.open(DB_NAME, NEW_DB_VERSION);
    req.onblocked = function () {
        console.log('blocked');
        db.close();
        var req = indexedDB.deleteDatabase(DB_NAME);
        req.onsuccess = function () {
            console.log('we ok');
        };
        req.onblocked = function () {
            console.log('still blocked');
        };
    };
}
```

Comment: What you're describing certainly sounds like a bug. The upgrade should be unblocked once all of the connections are closed. The only difference between closing in `versionchange` vs. closing later is whether or not the `blocked` is fired. I know we have tests for this case in Chrome, and Firefox should have them as well. Can you share a minimized sample?

Comment: I've revised the post to indicate that the problem is with `open()`->`open()`->`blocked listener`->`close() original`->`deleteDatabase`.

Comment: And added a working code sample

Comment: I have recently written a same test, to test the onblocked call. You can take a look at. I used the same logic as Joshua discribed. In the second request I use the on blocked call to close the existing connection en the success call to close my second call. https://github.com/kristofdegrave/indexedDBmock/blob/master/test/database.js#L239

Comment: Your project is very interesting, and ought to help those of us who could use a supplement to the spec to see how things are supposed to occur. FYI, the API of my fork of db.js with its own test for this issue is now at https://github.com/brettz9/db.js/blob/master/tests/specs/handlers.js#L133

Comment: Yw, I started this project because I have written my own wrapper around indexeddb and I wanted to get some more code coverage. I wanted to automate this, but then I had the issue that phantomJS didn't support the indexeddb API yet, so I started writting it myself :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're opening two connections but only closing one.

In `fireBlockedEvent` you're closing the connection opened via `open(DB_NAME, DB_VERSION)` (passed in as `db`). But you're never closing the connection opened in `fireBlockedEvent` itself via `open(DB_NAME, NEW_DB_VERSION)` before calling `deleteDatabase()`.

The delete request will be blocked until all connections are closed.

Since you're writing test code it's hard to suggest a specific fix without altering the semantics, but this would work:

```
function fireBlockedEvent (db) {
    var req = indexedDB.open(DB_NAME, NEW_DB_VERSION);
    req.onblocked = function () {
        console.log('blocked');
        // close the blocking connection:             
        db.close();
    };
    req.onsuccess = function (e) {
        // close the formerly blocked connection:
        e.target.result.close();

        var req = indexedDB.deleteDatabase(DB_NAME);
        req.onsuccess = function () {
            console.log('we ok');
        };
        req.onblocked = function () {
            console.log('still blocked');
        };
    };
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see, but shouldn't your comments be swapped since `db` has the original connection while the `onsuccess` would have the result of the most recent `open` attempt?

Comment: So to summarize... the old database must be closed (i.e., `db.close()`) in order for the `onsuccess` to get triggered (and without need for any new connection to do the triggering since blocking does not by default actually stop the connection). Then we have to wait for this current connection to be successful (i.e., `req.onsuccess`) in order to close it (i.e., `e.target.result.close();`) and then carry on (i.e., with the `deleteDatabase()`).

Comment: It was also confusing to me because while `open`, insists on triggering `onsuccess` once any old blocking connections were closed and forming a new connection (which in my case needed to also be closed), `deleteDatabase`--which shares the same interface--does not.

Comment: I've given you the answer as it does seem to work, but would appreciate answers to my clarifying questions if you wouldn't mind... Thanks!

Comment: re: "shouldn't your comments be swapped" - no; `db` holds the connection that *blocked* the second open, and in the `onsuccess` it's the new connection that only just became unblocked by the close.

Comment: Re: "to summarize" - yes, that's correct. The spec implies (but does not explicitly state) that there's a queue of open/delete requests for each named database. At most one request gets processed at a time. Once a version change request (open w/ higher version or delete) gets to the top of the queue it blocks the request queue until it is satisfied, and it can't be processed until all other connections are closed. It's slightly more complicated because delete requests get bumped to the start of the implied queue.

Comment: Re: `open` vs. `deleteDatabase` - if you can post a sample (or another issue, etc) showing the difference I might be able to clarify. They should behave similarly.